# Why does strapi relation to another table shown as ID instead of their name?

Tags: strapi

[image: strapi]

[image]

In strapi interface `activity_type` shown as their `name` field. But in data shown as their `id` instead of name. How to get name field instead of their id?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this section of the docs: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/rest/populate-select.